# java.lang.ClassCastException while creating a dataframe with schema

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have some incoming data as rowValues, I will have to apply a particular schema and create a data frame , here is my code:

```scala
val rowValues = List("12","F","1980-10-11,1980-10-11T10:10:20")
val rdd = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(rowValues))
val rowRdd = rdd.map(v => Row(v: _*))

var fieldSchema = ListBuffer[StructField]()

fieldSchema += StructField("C0", IntegerType, true, null)
fieldSchema += StructField("C1", StringType, true, null)
fieldSchema += StructField("C2", TimestampType, true, null)
val schema = StructType(fieldSchema.toList)

val newRow = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRdd, schema)
newRow.printSchema()   // new schema prints here
newRow.show()   // This fails with ClassCast exception
```

This fails with `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 16.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 16.0 (TID 16, localhost): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp`

How do I apply this schema?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than applying schema you can cast the column in dataframe as your schema

You can use withColumn to with cast function to change the datatype of column

Below is the simple example

```scala
import spark.implicits._

val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  ("12","F","1980-10-11T10:10:20"),
  ("12","F","1980-10-11T10:10:20")
)).toDF("c0", "c1", "c2")

val newDf = df.withColumn("c0", df("c0").cast(IntegerType))
  .withColumn("c2", df("c2").cast(TimestampType)) 
//cast string date to timestamp

val newDf = df.withColumn("c0", df("c0").cast(IntegerType))
  .withColumn("c2", to_utc_timestamp(df("c2"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
//to_utc_timestamp creates a timestamp form given column and date format

newDf.show(false)

newDf.printSchema()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much, this has helped , but what if the schema is of the following type:?In that case, I am not able to do typecast.                          |-- C2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Gender: string (nullable = true)

Comment: Yes, I would like to use my own schema too, the above withColumn/cast worked for primitive types , but how about custom schema, this schema will be known only at run time ... |-- C0: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- C1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- C2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Gender: string (nullable = true)

Answer (score 1):

your input data are all strings but your schema for `c0` is `integer`, `c1` is `string` and `c2` is `timestamp`, thus you are getting casting errors. Your string `timestamp` looks even more complicated.

If you are just looking for getting a `dataframe` you should change all columns `datatypes` to `string` and it will work

```
fieldSchema += StructField("C0", StringType, true, null)
fieldSchema += StructField("C1", StringType, true, null)
fieldSchema += StructField("C2", StringType, true, null)
```

you should have

```
+---+---+------------------------------+
|C0 |C1 |C2                            |
+---+---+------------------------------+
|12 |F  |1980-10-11,1980-10-11T10:10:20|
+---+---+------------------------------+
```

If you insist on staying with your schema, following code should give better ideas

```
val rowValues = List("12","F","1980-10-11,1980-10-11T10:10:20")
val rdd = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(rowValues))

val rowRdd = rdd.map(v => Row(v(0).toInt, v(1), v(2).split(",")(1).replace("T", " ")))

var fieldSchema = ListBuffer[StructField]()

fieldSchema += StructField("C0", IntegerType, true)
fieldSchema += StructField("C1", StringType, true)
fieldSchema += StructField("C2", StringType, true)
val schema = StructType(fieldSchema.toList)

val newRow = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRdd, schema).withColumn("C2", unix_timestamp(col("C2")))
newRow.printSchema()   // new schema prints here
newRow.show(false)
```

You can also do it with case class as

```
import sqlContext.implicits._

def convertToDate(dateTime: String): Timestamp = {
  val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
  val utilDate = formatter.parse(dateTime)
  new Timestamp(utilDate.getTime)
}
val rowValues = List("12","F","1980-10-11 10:10:20")
val rdd = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(rowValues))

val rowRdd = rdd.map(v => Pratap(v(0).toInt, v(1), convertToDate(v(2))))

val newRow = rowRdd.toDF
newRow.printSchema()   
newRow.show(false)
```

And your case class should be outside the main class as

```
case class Pratap(C0: Int, C1: String, C2: java.sql.Timestamp)
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, but I want this schema only-c0 is integer, c1 is string and c2 is timestamp, is there a way to create dataframe with this schema?

Comment: Thanks , I would like to use my own schema too, the above withColumn/cast worked for primitive types , but how about custom schema, this schema will be known only at run time ... |-- C0: integer (nullable = true) |-- C1: integer (nullable = true) |-- C2: struct (nullable = true) | |-- Gender: string (nullable = true)

Comment: updated my answer. :) if it still doesn't answer what you are looking for please explain what dynamic means

Comment: Thanks But I can’t define the case class right away since the schema will be known only at run time.  There should be a way to generate this depending on the incoming schema,. Another thing is the column types might not be primitive ones, there will be custom data types like AType, BType etc instead of int,string. So Is there a way to apply these custom data types?

Comment: can you elaborate on how you are creating dynamic schema ? you can update your question. :)